# Retrieving latest associated record in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I have 3 entities EntityA, EntityB and EntityC

EntityA can have many EntityB

EntityB will have one EntityC and a CreatedDate

I want to retrieve all EntityAs with the latest EntityB if one exists and associated EntityC.

I'm really struggling on the LINQ (lambda or otherwise). Can you help?

Comment: have you tried `Join`?

Comment: Yes but I am struggling with the syntax :-(

Comment: show us what you've tried because it will make easier to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityAs.Select(a=>new EntityA {
  EntityBs=a.EntityBs.OrderByDescending(b=>b.CreateDate).Take(1)});
```

If it is an EF entity, then you might need to include C, like this:

```
EntityAs
  .Include(a=>a.Select(b=>b.EntityC))
  .Select(a=>new EntityA {
    EntityBs=a.EntityBs.OrderByDescending(b=>b.CreateDate).Take(1)});
```